# AWS not letting me ssh into instance and cannot connect to my website due to timeout error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-ec2, certbot

1 hour ago I could connect to my website, stringapi.net, but now, it is taking too long to respond and I also cannot ssh into my instance as that is also not loading (I assume also timeout error). Does anybody have any suggestions? I just setup certbot a few days ago, could it be a problem with this?

I have checked and ec2 does not appear to be down.

Comment: Either the instance is legitimately down - Out-Of-Memory is a common cause on small instances like t3.nano - or the security group no longer allows access, or you have the Ip wrong

Comment: How would I check if it is out of memory?

Comment: First check the security group and that the public IP didn't change (which it will any time the instance is stopped).  If those look right, I'd just reboot the instance.  AWS can't introspect memory usage directly.

Comment: Is it a t2, or t3 instance? Is it out of CPU credits?

Comment: It is a t2 instance.

Comment: I am building a rest api. Would it be a good idea to use auto scaling if I do not know how many people will use the service?

Comment: it is a t2.micro instance

Comment: The security group and public ip are the same. I rebooted the instance and the site is still down. Should I try to setup autoscaling?

Comment: I rebooted it and it is now up, how do I make sure this doesent happen again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting the instance worked!